# $\sum_i \sum_j \sum_k (1 \le i \le j \le k \le n) ~~f_i f_j f_k $ in terms of $\sum f_i~, \sum f^2 _i ~\mbox{and}~ \sum f^3 _i $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

We often encounter triple sums such as 
    $$ S_1 = \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k (1 \le i \ne j \ne k \le n) ~~f_i f_j f_k $$
    $$ S_2 = \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k (1 \le i < j < k < n) ~~f_i f_j f_k $$
    $$ S_3 = \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k (1 \le i \le j \le k \le n) ~~f_i f_j f_k~. $$

I would like to know if $ S_1 , S_2 , S_3 $ can be expressed in terms of $\sum f_i~,\sum f^2 _i ~\mbox{and}~ \sum f^3 _i ~ . $ Please help.

Comment: Hint : if $n\geq 3$, each of $S_1,S_2,S_3$ contain $f_1f_2f_3$ which is not contained in any of $\sum f_i$, $\sum f_i^2$, $\sum f_i^3$

Comment: In $S_1$ replace $ k \ne n $ by $k \le n$.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Thanks, I have made the correction

Answer (score 7):

Yes, due to the the interesting identity:
$$(a+b+c)^3=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)-2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+6abc.$$ 
$S_1,S_2,S_3$ in your question can be expressed as:
$$S_1=\left(\sum_{i}f_i\right)^3-3 \left(\sum_i f^2_i \right) \left(\sum_i f_i\right)+2 \left(\sum_i f^3_i\right)$$

$$ S_2 = \frac{1}{6}\left[\left(\sum_{i}f_i\right)^3-3 \left(\sum_i f^2_i \right) \left(\sum_i f_i\right)+2 \left(\sum_i f^3_i\right)\right]$$

$$ S_3 = \frac{1}{6}\left[\left(\sum_{i}f_i\right)^3 -3\left(\sum_i f^2_i \right) \left(\sum_i f_i\right)  + 8\left(\sum_i f^3_i\right)\right] $$